How to count how many sites, libraries and documents shared with more as 50 users?
I would like to know how many sites, libraries and documents shared with more as 50 users. I write this PowerShell script, but it is very slow because we have thousands of SharePoint sites and 80 TB data. Does someone know which part could be optimized?
The hard part is that I need to check all the unique permissions on all levels (libraries, folders).
    function countInheritedPermissionFiles {
    param (
        [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientObject]$folder,
        [string]$listName
    )

    $folderItems = Get-PnPFolderItem -Identity $folder

    foreach($folderItem in $folderItems) {
        if($folderItem.TypedObject.ToString() -eq "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder") {
            $folderByPnP = Get-PnPFolder -Url $folderItem.ServerRelativeUrl -Includes ListItemAllFields.HasUniqueRoleAssignments, Folders
 
            if(!$folderByPnP.ListItemAllFields.HasUniqueRoleAssignments) {
                countInheritedPermissionFiles $folderByPnP $listName
            }
        } else {
            $item = Get-PnPListItem -List $listName -UniqueId  $folderItem.UniqueId

            $HasUniquePermissions = Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $item[0] -Property "HasUniqueRoleAssignments"

            if(!$HasUniquePermissions) {
                $global:inheritedPermissionsFileCount ++
            }
        }
    }
}

function getPermissions($_object) {

    # make arrays empty
    $global:permissionUsers = @()
    $global:permissionType = @()
    $global:permissionLevels = @()

    $roleAssignments = Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $_object -Property RoleAssignments
  
    #Loop through each permission assigned and extract details   
    Foreach($roleAssignment in $_object.RoleAssignments)
    {
        #Get the Permission Levels assigned and Member
        Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $roleAssignment -Property RoleDefinitionBindings, Member

        if($roleAssignment.Member.LoginName -notlike "*Limited Access*" -and $roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings[0].Name -notlike "*Beperkte toegang*" -and $roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings[0].Name -notlike "*Limited Access*") {
            #Get the Permission Levels assigned, Remove Limited Access
            foreach($roleDefinitionBinding in $roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings) {
                if(!$global:permissionLevels.Contains($roleDefinitionBinding.Name)) {
                    $global:permissionLevels += $roleDefinitionBinding.Name
                }
            }

            #Check if the Principal is SharePoint group
            If($roleAssignment.Member.PrincipalType -eq "SharePointGroup")
            {
                if(!$global:permissionType.Contains("SharePointGroup")) {
                    $global:permissionType += "SharePointGroup"
                }

                #Get Group Members
                $GroupMembers = Get-PnPGroupMember -Identity $roleAssignment.Member.LoginName

                foreach($groupMember in $GroupMembers) {
                    if(!$global:permissionUsers.Contains($groupMember.Email) -and $groupMember.LoginName -notlike "*c:0o.c|federateddirectoryclaimprovider|*" -and $groupMember.Email -ne "") {
                        $global:permissionUsers += $groupMember.Email
                    }   
                }
            }
            Else #User
            {
                if(!$global:permissionType.Contains("DirectUser")) {
                    $global:permissionType += "DirectUser"
                }

                if(!$global:permissionUsers.Contains($roleAssignment.Member.Email)) {
                    $global:permissionUsers += $roleAssignment.Member.Email
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

#Parameters
$dateTime = (Get-Date).toString("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss")
$invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation).Value
$directorypath = Split-Path $invocation.MyCommand.Path
$fileName = "M365OversharingReport.csv"
$reportOutput = $directorypath + "\Report\"+ $fileName
$traceLoggingFolderPath = $directorypath + "\Logs\"
$traceLoggingFilename = "transcript-${datetime}.log"
$transcriptLogFileFullPath = Join-Path -Path $traceLoggingFolderPath -ChildPath $traceLoggingFilename
$global:permissionUsers = @()
$global:permissionType = @()
$global:permissionLevels = @()
$global:inheritedPermissionsFileCount = 0
$recordsCount = 0
$minUsersCount = 50
$adminSiteURL = "https://myCompany-admin.sharepoint.com"
$tenant =  "myCompany.onmicrosoft.com"
$spSiteDomain = "https://myCompany.sharepoint.com"
$certThumbprint = "something"
$appId = "someGuid"

LogEntry("START")

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $adminSiteURL -ClientId $appId -Thumbprint $certThumbprint -Tenant $tenant

$excludedSites = @("https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/sites/AppCatalog", "https://myCompany-my.sharepoint.com/", "https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/", "https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/search", "https://myCompany.sharepoint.com/sites/allcompany")
$excludedLists = @("Access Requests", "App Packages", "appdata", "appfiles", "Apps in Testing", "Cache Profiles", "Composed Looks", "Content and Structure Reports", "Content type publishing error log", "Converted Forms",
    "Device Channels", "Form Templates", "fpdatasources", "Get started with Apps for Office and SharePoint", "List Template Gallery", "Long Running Operation Status", "Maintenance Log Library", "Images", "site collection images"
    , "Master Docs", "Master Page Gallery", "MicroFeed", "NintexFormXml", "Quick Deploy Items", "Relationships List", "Reusable Content", "Reporting Metadata", "Reporting Templates", "Search Config List", "Site Assets", "Preservation Hold Library",
    "Site Pages", "Solution Gallery", "Style Library", "Suggested Content Browser Locations", "Theme Gallery", "TaxonomyHiddenList", "User Information List", "Web Part Gallery", "wfpub", "wfsvc", "Workflow History", "Workflow Tasks", "Pages")

# Haal alle sitecollecties op
LogEntry("Get all SharePoint sites")
$sitesCollection = Get-PnPTenantSite

LogEntry("Found '$($sitesCollection.Count)' SharePoint sites")

# Read CSV and to skip the processed sites
$processedSites = @()
if (Test-Path $reportOutput) {
    
    $processedSites = Import-Csv $reportOutput | Where-Object { $_.Status -eq "ProcessedOversharing" -or $_.Status -eq "ProcessedExcludedSite" -or $_.Status -eq "ProcessedNoOversharing"  } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SiteUrl
    LogEntry("Found '$($processedSites.Count)' SharePoint sites already analysed in CSV file")
}

$siteCounter = 0

# Loop into all sitecollection
ForEach($site in $sitesCollection) {
    $siteCounter++
    LogEntry("Site $siteCounter / $($sitesCollection.Count)")
    
    # Check if this site is already processed
    if ($processedSites -contains $site.Url) {
        LogEntry("Site $($site.Url) is already processed, skip it and do nothing...")
        continue
    }

    if(!$excludedSites.Contains($site.Url) -and !$site.Url.Contains(($spSiteDomain + "/portals"))) {
        Connect-PnPOnline -Url $site.Url -ClientId $appId -Thumbprint $certThumbprint -Tenant $tenant
        $skipped = $true
        $owners = ""
        If($Site.Template -like 'GROUP*') {
            # Get M365 Group owner
            try {
                $owners = (Get-PnPMicrosoft365GroupOwners -Identity ($Site.GroupId)  | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Email) -join "; "
            }
            Catch [Exception] {}
        } Else {
            # Get site owner
            try {                
                $ownergroup = Get-PnPGroup -AssociatedOwnerGroup
                $owners = ($ownergroup.Users | Where-Object { $_.Email -ne $null } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Email) -join "; "
            }
            Catch [Exception] {}
        }

        try {
            $web = Get-PnPWeb
            $libraries = Get-PnPList -Includes BaseType, Hidden, Title, HasUniqueRoleAssignments, RootFolder | Where-Object {$_.Hidden -eq $False -and $_.Title -notin $excludedLists -and $_.BaseType -eq "DocumentLibrary" }

            $siteListItemsCount = 0
            LogEntry("Process '$($libraries.Count)' libraries")
            
            foreach($library in $libraries) {
                $siteListItemsCount += $library.ItemCount

                if($library.HasUniqueRoleAssignments) {
                    getPermissions $library

                    if($global:permissionUsers.Count -gt $minUsersCount) {
                        $recordsCount++

                        LogEntry("Site $siteCounter / $($sitesCollection.Count), save record $recordsCount (library) '$($site.Url)$($library.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl)'")
                        
                        $libraryAccessItem = New-Object PSObject
                        $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "SharePointObjectType" -NotePropertyValue "Library"
                        $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "UsersCount" -NotePropertyValue $global:permissionUsers.Count
                        $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "ItemsCount" -NotePropertyValue $library.ItemCount
                        $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "PermissionInheritedItemsCount" -NotePropertyValue $library.ItemCount
                        $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "SiteUrl" -NotePropertyValue $site.Url
                        $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "ListUrl" -NotePropertyValue $library.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl
                        $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "ServerRelativeUrl" -NotePropertyValue $library.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl
                        $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "LinkType" -NotePropertyValue ($global:permissionLevels -join '|')
                        $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "SharedLinkOrDirectAccess" -NotePropertyValue "DirectAccess"
                        $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "DirectPermissionType" -NotePropertyValue ($global:permissionType -join '|')
                        $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Users" -NotePropertyValue ($global:permissionUsers -join '|')
                        $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Owners" -NotePropertyValue $Owners
                        $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "SiteTemplate" -NotePropertyValue $site.Template
                        $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Status" -NotePropertyValue "ProcessedOversharing"
                        $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "ErrorMessage" -NotePropertyValue ""

                        # Save row to CSV
                        $libraryAccessItem | Export-CSV $reportOutput -Append -NoTypeInformation
                        $skipped = $false
                    }
                } 

                # Get documents from library
                $listItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $library -PageSize 2000 # TODO, Check if I get more as 2000 results
                LogEntry("Process '$($listItems.Count)' documents from library '$($library.Title)'")

                ForEach($item in $listItems) {
                    # Check if this document has unique permissions
                    $hasUniquePermissions = Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $Item -Property "HasUniqueRoleAssignments"
                    If($hasUniquePermissions) {
                        getPermissions $item

                        if($global:permissionUsers.Count -gt $minUsersCount) {
                            $recordsCount++
                            
                            LogEntry("Site $siteCounter / $($sitesCollection.Count), save record $recordsCount (document) '$($site.Url)$($item.FieldValues["FileRef"])'")
                            
                            $directAccessItem = New-Object PSObject
                            if ($item.FileSystemObjectType -eq "Folder") {
                                # Get documents and folders
                                $folderRelativePath = $item.FieldValues["FileRef"].Replace($web.ServerRelativeUrl,"")
                                $items = Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $folderRelativePath -Recursive -ItemType File
                                $directAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "SharePointObjectType" -NotePropertyValue "Folder"
                                $directAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "UsersCount" -NotePropertyValue $global:permissionUsers.Count
                                $directAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "ItemsCount" -NotePropertyValue $items.Count
                                
                                # Initialiseer bestandstelling
                                $global:inheritedPermissionsFileCount = 0

                                $folder = Get-PnPFolder -Url $item.FieldValues["FileRef"] -Includes Files, Folders

                                # Count documents from this subfolder
                                countInheritedPermissionFiles $folder $library.Title

                                $directAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "PermissionInheritedItemsCount" -NotePropertyValue $global:inheritedPermissionsFileCount
                            } else {
                                $directAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "SharePointObjectType" -NotePropertyValue "File"
                                $directAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "UsersCount" -NotePropertyValue $global:permissionUsers.Count
                                $directAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "ItemsCount" -NotePropertyValue "N/A"
                                $directAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "PermissionInheritedItemsCount" -NotePropertyValue "N/A"        
                            }

                            $directAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "SiteUrl" -NotePropertyValue $site.Url
                            $directAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "ListUrl" -NotePropertyValue $library.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl
                            $directAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "ServerRelativeUrl" -NotePropertyValue $item.FieldValues["FileRef"]
                            $directAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "RoleList" -NotePropertyValue "TODO"
                            $directAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "LinkScope" -NotePropertyValue "TODO"
                            $directAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "LinkType" -NotePropertyValue ($global:permissionLevels -join '|')

                            $SharingLinks = if ($item.FileSystemObjectType -eq "File") {
                                Get-PnPFileSharingLink -Identity $item.FieldValues["FileRef"]
                            } elseif ($item.FileSystemObjectType -eq "Folder") {
                                Get-PnPFolderSharingLink -Folder $item.FieldValues["FileRef"]
                            }

                            if($SharingLinks) {
                                $directAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "SharedLinkOrDirectAccess" -NotePropertyValue "DirectAccess/SharedLinks"
                            } else {
                                $directAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "SharedLinkOrDirectAccess" -NotePropertyValue "DirectAccess"
                            }

                            $directAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "DirectPermissionType" -NotePropertyValue ($global:permissionType -join '|')
                            $directAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Users" -NotePropertyValue ($global:permissionUsers -join '|')
                            $directAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Owners" -NotePropertyValue $Owners                          
                            $directAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "SiteTemplate" -NotePropertyValue $site.Template
                            $directAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Status" -NotePropertyValue "ProcessedOversharing"
                            $directAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "ErrorMessage" -NotePropertyValue ""

                            # Save row to CSV
                            $directAccessItem | Export-CSV $reportOutput -Append -NoTypeInformation
                            $skipped = $false
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            getPermissions $web
            if($global:permissionUsers.Count -gt $minUsersCount) {
                $recordsCount++

                LogEntry("Site $siteCounter / $($sitesCollection.Count), save record $recordsCount (site) '$($site.Url)'")

                $siteAccessItem = New-Object PSObject
                $siteAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "SharePointObjectType" -NotePropertyValue "Site"
                $siteAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "UsersCount" -NotePropertyValue $global:permissionUsers.Count
                $siteAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "ItemsCount" -NotePropertyValue $siteListItemsCount
                $siteAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "PermissionInheritedItemsCount" -NotePropertyValue $siteListItemsCount
                $siteAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "SiteUrl" -NotePropertyValue $site.Url
                $siteAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "ListUrl" -NotePropertyValue "N/A"
                $siteAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "ServerRelativeUrl" -NotePropertyValue $web.ServerRelativeUrl
                $siteAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "LinkType" -NotePropertyValue ($global:permissionLevels -join '|')
                $siteAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "SharedLinkOrDirectAccess" -NotePropertyValue "DirectAccess"
                $siteAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "DirectPermissionType" -NotePropertyValue ($global:permissionType -join '|')
                $siteAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Users" -NotePropertyValue ($global:permissionUsers -join '|')
                $siteAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Owners" -NotePropertyValue $Owners
                $siteAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "SiteTemplate" -NotePropertyValue $site.Template
                $siteAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Status" -NotePropertyValue "ProcessedOversharing"
                $siteAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "ErrorMessage" -NotePropertyValue ""

                # Save row to CSV
                $siteAccessItem | Export-CSV $reportOutput -Append -NoTypeInformation
                $skipped = $false
            }
        }
        catch [Exception] {
            LogEntry("Catch error: " + $_.Exception.Message)
        }

        if($skipped) {
            $libraryAccessItem = New-Object PSObject
            $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "SharePointObjectType" -NotePropertyValue "ProcessedNoOversharing"
            $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "UsersCount" -NotePropertyValue "ProcessedNoOversharing"
            $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "ItemsCount" -NotePropertyValue "ProcessedNoOversharing"
            $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "PermissionInheritedItemsCount" -NotePropertyValue "ProcessedNoOversharing"
            $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "SiteUrl" -NotePropertyValue $site.Url
            $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "ListUrl" -NotePropertyValue "ProcessedNoOversharing"
            $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "ServerRelativeUrl" -NotePropertyValue "ProcessedNoOversharing"
            $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "LinkType" -NotePropertyValue "ProcessedNoOversharing"
            $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "SharedLinkOrDirectAccess" -NotePropertyValue "ProcessedNoOversharing"
            $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "DirectPermissionType" -NotePropertyValue "ProcessedNoOversharing"
            $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Users" -NotePropertyValue "ProcessedNoOversharing"
            $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Owners" -NotePropertyValue "ProcessedNoOversharing"
            $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "SiteTemplate" -NotePropertyValue "ProcessedNoOversharing"
            $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Status" -NotePropertyValue "ProcessedNoOversharing"
            $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "ErrorMessage" -NotePropertyValue ""

            # Save row to CSV
            $libraryAccessItem | Export-CSV $reportOutput -Append -NoTypeInformation
        }

    } else {
        $libraryAccessItem = New-Object PSObject
        $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "SharePointObjectType" -NotePropertyValue "Site"
        $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "UsersCount" -NotePropertyValue "ProcessedExcludedSite"
        $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "ItemsCount" -NotePropertyValue "ProcessedExcludedSite"
        $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "PermissionInheritedItemsCount" -NotePropertyValue "ProcessedExcludedSite"
        $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "SiteUrl" -NotePropertyValue $site.Url
        $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "ListUrl" -NotePropertyValue "ProcessedExcludedSite"
        $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "ServerRelativeUrl" -NotePropertyValue "ProcessedExcludedSite"
        $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "LinkType" -NotePropertyValue "ProcessedExcludedSite"
        $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "SharedLinkOrDirectAccess" -NotePropertyValue "ProcessedExcludedSite"
        $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "DirectPermissionType" -NotePropertyValue "ProcessedExcludedSite"
        $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Users" -NotePropertyValue "ProcessedExcludedSite"
        $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Owners" -NotePropertyValue "ProcessedExcludedSite"
        $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "SiteTemplate" -NotePropertyValue "ProcessedExcludedSite"
        $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Status" -NotePropertyValue "ProcessedExcludedSite"
        $libraryAccessItem | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "ErrorMessage" -NotePropertyValue ""

        # save row in CSV
        $libraryAccessItem | Export-CSV $reportOutput -Append -NoTypeInformation
    }
} else {
    break
}

LogEntry("Sharing Links Report Generated Successfully $reportOutput")
LogEntry("FINISHED")

